# cordova file upload to google blobstore

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, cordova, blobstore

In my cordova application I want to upload a file to google blobstore. But there is some error in `<input type="file">` on android 4.4. Is there a way to upload files to blobstore without using `<input type="file">`? I tried using file-transfer plugin but it doesn't return create a blobkey for the uploaded file (I don't know the exact problem.)

Comment: Form submission is required for Blobstore API. Have you considered moving to Google Cloud Storage + endpoints instead?

Comment: Yeah I realized that soon, so created a custom cordova plugin to multipart form data requests and used it in conjugation with file chooser plugin ... :)